# Update SQL database date column

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

i have SQL server database and table with column for date (date datatype). I would like to change the value of date column for all records to have todays date, but something is not working, please help. My code:

```
 con.Open();
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
 string insStr = "UPDATE tblBusiness SET DateCreated = @Date;";
 SqlCommand updateDate = new SqlCommand(insStr, con);
 updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", date);
 updateDate.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

Thanks, Oak

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers.
The thing why it was not working was because of too many records in database and the default update timeout is 30sec or something. And thats why no record was changed.
updateDate.CommandTimeout = 0; fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.
The thing why it was not working was because of too many records in database and the default update timeout is 30sec or something. And thats why no record was changed.
updateDate.CommandTimeout = 0; fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.
The thing why it was not working was because of too many records in database and the default update timeout is 30sec or something. And thats why no record was changed.
updateDate.CommandTimeout = 0; fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think this line:

```
updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", date);
```

Should be:

```
updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
```

Answer (score 2):

use `@Date` instead of `Date`

```
updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Replace
updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", date);

// with (watch the @-symbol)
updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Date` with `@Date`.

```
updateDate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work. You don't need a where clause if you are updating all records.

```
con.Open();
 DateTime date = DateTime.Now.Date;
 string insStr = "UPDATE tblBusiness SET DateCreated = " + date;
 SqlCommand updateDate = new SqlCommand(insStr, con);
 updateDate.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

Comment: You had better have one (unless you want to update all records)

Comment: You guys are correct. I misread the question. But I have revised my answer.